# Power of solar panel and dc generator

Tags: power, solar-cells

I have made a solar stirling engine and I need to measure its power and compare it to the output power of a solar panel. I need to see which one is more efficient. I am using the same area in both systems for heat/light absorption and two 100 watt light bulbs for heat/light production.

For the dc generator which gets it's torque from the engine, I can connect a resistor in parallel and measure the terminal voltage. Then I can use this law (P = V^2 / R) to calculate power.

AFAIK, solar panels do not exactly work in the same way as dc generators or batteries or voltage sources. So, how can I calculate output power of the solar panel?

Thanks